# Message Box won't work in IF statement

Tags: vba

I am trying to write some code that loops through a column and gives a warning if the cell contains any values other than "buy" or "sel". It should exit the sub on OK and continue on cancel, however it is not finding the buy and sell values as all my test cells have "buy" or "sell" and the message box still appears. Please advise.

```
Set TransSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
LastCell = TransSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim MsgBoxTrans As Long
For a = LastCell To 2
    v = Cells(a, 10).Value
    If v <> "buy" Or v <> "sel" Then
        MsgBoxTrans = MsgBox("Transaction exists other than BUY or SEL, please filter and check", vbOKCancel, "Warning - Press Cancel to Skip")
        If MsgBoxTrans = vbOK Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Else
        End If
    a = a - 1
Next a
```

Comment: `v <> "buy" Or v <> "sel"` will always be true, because at least one of those conditions will always be true, i.e., it's either not going to be "buy" or it's not going to be "sell." Change it to `v <> "buy" And v <> "sel"`

Answer (score 0):

Doug explained the logical problem in your code. Here we can make some additional improvements here:

```
Set TransSheet = Application.ActiveSheet
LastCell = TransSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'This variable not really needed:
'Dim MsgBoxTrans As Long

'## Declare your variable "v" as Variant
Dim v as Variant

'## Force "Step -1" rather than using the clunky "a = a-1":

For a = LastCell To 2 Step -1
    v = Cells(a, 10).Value
    If v <> "buy" AND v <> "sel" Then
        '## Evaluate the MsgBox object, assign the button type to "vbOkCancel" so that
        '   it will either be OK (exit sub) or Cancel, which will continue uninterupted
        If MsgBox("Transaction exists other than BUY or SEL, please filter and check", _
                  "Warning - Press Cancel to Skip", vbOkCancel) = vbOK Then Exit Sub
    'Get rid of this "Else" because you're not using it:
    'Else  
    End If
Next a
```